# Why does this code not cause a buffer overflow?

Tags: c++

I want to write code that causes a buffer overflow. Could you give me some advice on why my test code below does not cause a buffer overflow?

I think a buffer overflow should occur on this line:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

#define buffer_size 10

int main(){
    string m_string = "My name is String";
    char* node_reference = new char[buffer_size];
    unsigned int len = strlen(m_string.c_str());
    unsigned int buffer_len = sizeof(node_reference)/sizeof(char);
    std::printf("len: %d\n", len);
    std::printf("buffer len: %d\n", buffer_len);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < strlen(m_string.c_str()) + 1; i++) {
        node_reference[i] = m_string[i];
        std::printf("index: %d and value: %c\n", i, node_reference[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**
I removed typo de_referece line. Thank you for your kind answers to the insufficient questions.

Comment: In this line `de_reference[i] = m_string[i];`, `i` is not defined.

Comment: Where does `i` come from? It isn't defined in the function

Comment: Change `i < strlen(m_string.c_str()) + 1` to `i < strlen(m_string.c_str())` in the loop and  delete line 12.

Comment: @Dan yes, it is. It is defined in the `for` loop

Comment: @RemyLebeau it is used in the third line of the main function before being defined: `de_reference[i] = m_string[i];` -- which I suspect is a typo since it should probably be `node_reference` not `de_reference`

Comment: `node_reference` is a pointer, not an array, so sizeof won't give the size of the allocated "array"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sizeof(node_reference)` does not do what you think it does, since `node_reference` is allocated dynamically. You are obtaining the size of the pointer itself, not the size of the allocated buffer being pointed at. Your `printf()` of `buffer_len` should have indicated that to you.  `sizeof(node_reference)` would work only if `node_reference` had been allocated statically instead.

That being said, your code **does** cause a buffer overflow.  You are allocating **10 bytes** for `node_reference` and then writing **18 bytes** into it.  The behavior is undefined, so *anything* can happen.  A crash is not *guaranteed*, if that is what you are expecting.  You are certainly corrupting memory, though it may not be memory you would normally see since it is outside of your allocation.